# How do I remove an object in an array every time a button is clicked?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

An object in an array is randomly selected using an integer and displayed in a label. Then I remove that object from the array so the same object isn't displayed in the label twice. However, my approach isn't working.

How do I fix this code?
Here is what I have so far:

```
NSMutableArray *Array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Obj1",
                                             @"Obj2",
                                             @"Obj3",
                                             @"Obj4",
                                             @"Obj5", nil];
int randNum = arc4random() % [_Array count];
NSString *Object1 =[self.mobility1ExerciseNameArray objectAtIndex:randNum];
self.lbl_ObjectName.text = Object1;
[_Array removeObjectAtIndex:randNum];
```

Answer (score 0):

AIn the code you put here you are using two different Array names. First you use:

```
Array
```

but then, on the objectatindex message you use another array called mobility1ExerciseNameArray:

```
[self.mobility1ExerciseNameArray objectAtIndex:randNum];
```

I'm not sure if this is the real issue or if this is some copy_paste error. Check it

Comment: Sorry thats just a cut and paste error. mobility1ExerciseNameArray is actually supposed to be Array